# On what domain my computer is working?

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking, lan, domain-name

I am using my institute's LAN and I wanted to use Remote Desktop Connection app to connect to a friend's laptop on the same network.

I have his IP address but do not have Domain Name and actually I do not understand what exactly (username@domain) means.

I have googled a lot and even the Microsoft Website does not have a help paeg for this.

My Computer Properties is not showing anything. Here's snapshot:

[image: Properties]

Comment: Looks like you don't belong to any domain: the "Domain" is missing in your settings, only Workgroup instead ...

Comment: So How do I use mstsc?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing an IP address is sufficient enough for you to reach your friends machine. 
In case you didn't know his IP address you would need to know his hostname, to ask DNS server for his IP address. If there is a domain on your institute's network you can also write his address in hostname.domain.tld format, eg. alex-PC.foocorp.com in case that yours instituion domain is foocorp.

You can try login using just his username and password. It depends on protocol, you are going to use to reach your friends computer. If it is through Windows File Sharing then providing no such domain should be needed. In case you have accounts maintained by your institution, you might actually need the domain. It could be actually address of your instituion (foocorp.com). 
You can look for connection-specific DNS suffix which is found in details of your network adapter or fire up cmd.exe (command prompt) and type command ipconfig. You should see that.

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to use Windows Remote Desktop Connection App.

Comment: And there is no domain name in ipconfig either. It just have four rows viz. Link-local IPv6, IPv4 Address, Subnet Mask and Default Gateway. That's all.